# Multicolor tab bar icon

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm working on app for one restaurant.

I have tab bar with 3 items (home, food, cart).

I need to change the icon of cart tab bar item when user adds or removes something from cart (changing icons isn't problem).

I have PNGs with cart and red circle with numbers from 1 to 9 on top of it. And that's the problem, the icon has two colors (red circle and gray cart).

I tried set tint Color to clear, but it didn't work.

Comment: Would it not be confusing for the end user to have multicoloured tabbar icons - how would they know what one theyve picked

Comment: I would have to have two images, one with darker gray and one with lighter gray (for each number). One would be self.tabBar.items![2].image and second self.tabBar.items![2].selectedImage.

Answer (score 1):

please you can use [RDVTabBarController](https://github.com/robbdimitrov/RDVTabBarController)

here is sample code

```
UIViewController *firstViewController = [[RDVFirstViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                               initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

UIViewController *secondViewController = [[RDVSecondViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];

UIViewController *thirdViewController = [[RDVThirdViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *thirdNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                               initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController];

RDVTabBarController *tabBarController = [[RDVTabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController,
                                       thirdNavigationController]];
self.viewController = tabBarController;


UIImage *finishedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected_background"];
UIImage *unfinishedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_normal_background"];
NSArray *tabBarItemImages = @[@"first", @"second", @"third"];

RDVTabBar *tabBar = [tabBarController tabBar];

[tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(tabBar.frame), CGRectGetMinY(tabBar.frame), CGRectGetWidth(tabBar.frame), 63)];

NSInteger index = 0;
for (RDVTabBarItem *item in [[tabBarController tabBar] items]) {
    [item setBackgroundSelectedImage:finishedImage withUnselectedImage:unfinishedImage];
    UIImage *selectedimage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_selected",
                                                  [tabBarItemImages objectAtIndex:index]]];
    UIImage *unselectedimage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_normal",
                                                    [tabBarItemImages objectAtIndex:index]]];
    [item setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedimage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedimage];

    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C :**

Put this in the `AppDelegate.m` in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME_FOR_SELECTED"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:selectedImage];
```

**Swift 2.1 :**

Put this in the `AppDelegate.swift` in `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)` method

```
let selectedImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME_FOR_SELECTED")!
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = selectedImage
```

> with an image name `"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME_FOR_SELECTED"` of size `98x98` pixels

Answer (score 0):

make the rendering mode of the image to always original?
`vc.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named:"icon")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into `UITabBarItem`'s `badgeValue` property, which is the recommended way of doing what you're trying to achieve (presumably a count of the user's basket).

An example of where you can see it is the App Store: It will look like the number of updates you can install badged onto the 'Updates' tab bar item.